# Confused about the buildin method __str__() on integer

Tags: python, class

We know that **str**() method defined in the object class allows us to convert an object into a string.

It works fine for some Python's buildin data classes, for example, if you invoke the **str**() method for float 5.0, it will return '5.0'.

However, I encountered a SyntaxError.
The code block below shows the proble.

Why doesn't this method work properly for integer?

```
>>> 5.__str__()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    5.__str__()
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a = 5
>>> a.__str__()
'5'
>>> (5).__str__()
'5'
>>> 5.0.__str__()
'5.0'
>>>
```